# Json creation in ruby for a list

Tags: arrays, ruby, json

I am new to Ruby.

I want to create a JSON file for a group of elements.

For this, I am using `each`function to retrieve the datas. I want to create json as follows for the 4 length array,

```
'{   
  "desc":{  
    "1":"1st Value",
    "2":"2nd value"
    "3":"3rd Value",
    "4":"4th value"
  },
}'
```

This is my array iteration,

```
REXML::XPath.each( doc, "//time" ) { |element1|  
  puts element1.get_text  
}
```

I know here is the simple code to generate a JSON,

```
require 'json/add/core'

class Item < Struct.new(:id, :name); end

chair = Item.new(1, 'chair')
puts JSON.pretty_generate(chair)
```

This syntax will generate a json as follows,

```
{
  "json_class": "Item",
  "v": [
    1,
    "chair"
  ]
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do that to make JSON for my elements as stated above. Google search didn't give me a proper way to do this.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: It is not clear :  from which data do you want to create a JSON output ? And what specific JSON output do you want ?

Comment: Your first JSON code isn't valid! First of all there is a comma missing after the `2nd value` and secondly there is a comma to much at the end of the `desc` hash. Please check your JSON with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) before you post it.

Answer (score 0):

it means this?:

```
require 'json'

my_arr= ["1st Value","2nd Value","3rd Value","4th Value"]

tmp_str= {} 
tmp_str["desc"] = {}

my_arr.each do |x|
    tmp_str["desc"]["#{x[0]}"] = x 
end
puts JSON.generate(tmp_str)
```

you can iterate  the string array ,then take the strings to hash object.JSON can easy to parse Hash objcect .

Comment: you can certainly put more explanation to your answer.

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.