# JSON creation for float values in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, json

I followed this answer to get the json as I expected.

[Json creation in ruby for a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955811/json-creation-in-ruby-for-a-list)

If I used that method I am able to generate json for string values.

Suppose if I have float values in array and iterate over them to produce the json, it wont generate JSON as expected, it generates only the last value in that array,

Here is the code I tried,

```
my_arr = ["1015.62","1014.08","1012.1","1019.09","1018.9","1019.86","1019.84"]

tmp_str = {} 
tmp_str["desc"] = {}

my_arr.each do |x|
    tmp_str["desc"]["#{x[0]}"] = x
    puts 'array'
end

puts JSON.generate(tmp_str)
```

The above code generates the following json

```
{"desc":{"1":"1019.84"}}
```

But I want to have the json as follows,

```
{"desc":{"1":"1015.62","2":"1014.08","3":"1012.1","4":"1019.09","5":"1018.9","6":"1019.86","7":"1019.84"}}
```

Where I need to change my code to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close just change the following

```
my_arr.each_with_index do |x,i|
   tmp_str["desc"]["#{i+1}"] = x
end
```

Output when you do

```
puts JSON.generate(tmp_str)

{"desc":{"1":"1015.62","2":"1014.08","3":"1012.1","4":"1019.09","5":"1018.9","6":"1019.86","7":"1019.84"}}
```

Comment: If I want to get json as ---------- {"desc":{"a":"1015.62","a":"1014.08","a":"1012.1","a":"1019.09","a":"1018.9","a":"1019.86","a":"1084.12}------------- not 1,2.... as keys. is this possible inside each function?

Comment: tmp_str["desc"]["a"] = x

Comment: I triesd that, but it generates only one json element and not all the 6

Comment: But, I need the json in that format. is there any other possible in ruby to gert that?

Comment: One possible is for key "a" you can put all the values is that ok

Comment: Infact I tried this for other reasons to create a chart. for that I need json like this only.

Comment: tmp_str = {}       tmp_str["desc"]["a"] = my_arr       puts JSON.generate(tmp_str)                        Output : {"desc":{"a":["1015.62","1014.08","1012.1","1019.09","1018.9","1019.86","1019.84"]}}, loop through it and put the values of a into chart